# socketio no logro iniciar sesión en nodejs

Tags: nodejs, socket.io

tengo un chat en react y en nodejs de backend...

y necesito pasarlo a html y javascript para adaptarlo dentro de un CRM...

Hice este código en Laravel y me conecta y autentica a la perfección... pero estoy teniendo problemas en hacerlo con JavaScript...

```
$username = "admin@admin.com";
        $password = "admin";
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

            $url2 = "http://localhost:8080/auth/login";

            $result2 = $client->request('POST', $url2, [
                'headers' => [
                    'Accept'     => 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2FybmFtZSI6IkFkbWluaXN0cmFkb3IiLCJwcm9maWxlIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJpZCI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNjUwOTAzNjc0LCJleHAiOjE2NTA5MDQ1NzR9.jwigscbirO6hUPiGdu5KoiVctLfw53WUbqyrnaqlQjg'
                ],
                'json' => [
                    'token' => 'jrt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2FybmFtZSI6IkFkbWluaXN0cmFkb3IiLCJwcm9maWxlIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJpZCI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNjUwOTAzNjc0LCJleHAiOjE2NTA5MDQ1NzR9.jwigscbirO6hUPiGdu5KoiVctLfw53WUbqyrnaqlQjg',
                    'email' => $username,
                    'password' => $password,
                ],
            ]);

            return $result2;
```

estuve intentando algo asi:

```
<script>
      // client code here
      var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080', {
    query: 'token=eydhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2FybmFtZSI6IkFkbWluaXN0cmFkb3IiLCJwcm9maWxlIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJpZCI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNjUwOTE0MDg2LCJleHAiOjE2NTA5MTQ5ODZ9.t48kxGSxADLXbYa7bgBicCLcWK-vSUjK8wSIYbdSPRI'
  });
      socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('authenticated');
  }).on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('disconnected');
  });
      $('#login').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post('http://localhost:8080/auth/login', {

    email: "admin@admin.com",
    password: "admin",
  }).done(function (result) {
    connect_socket(result.token);
  });
});
    </script>
```

y siempre obtengo:

```
 ERROR: WHERE parameter "email" has invalid "undefined" value
    Error: WHERE parameter "email" has invalid "undefined" value
```

El token lo estoy enviando manualmente sacado desde el laravel ya que tampoco logro con JavaScript generar el token.

me podrian decir en que estoy fallando?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que me parece que es que te falta es 1 header para especificar que tu `body` es del tipo JSON.

Debería ser algo cómo esto:

```
$("#login").submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/auth/login",
    data: {
      email: "admin@admin.com",
      password: "admin",
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  });
});
```

Comment: Hola gracias por tu tiempo, bien con eso me envia: SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0\n    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)\n    at createStrictSyntaxError

Comment: Qué versión de Node.js, y librerías para hacer el request estás usando?

Comment: Uso las dependencias cors express jsonwebtoken socket.io, y node 17.0.1